# How do I select an object in the 3D viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools

I am trying to select the cube that in the middle of the scene. How can I select it? All I see is a crosshair appearing everywhere I click. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 14):

That circle/crosshair is the [*3D cursor*](http://blendersushi.blogspot.com/2011/07/ui-that-pesky-3d-cursor.html).

To select you need to *Right click* instead of *Left click*.
You can change this behavior in *File > User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>) *> Input*:

1. Open the *User Preferences*:

[image: File > User prefs]

2. Go to the *Input* tab. The select left/right options are under *Mouse*:

[image: Set preferences]

3. If you want to save these settings as the default for the next time you open blender, click  *Save User Settings* in the *Header* (at the bottom of the window):

[image: Save user settings]

This is one of the most controversial parts of blenders UI.

For some further information you might want to check out:

- ["Fixing Blender – Part 1: Why It’s Broken" by Andrew Price](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/09/26/fixing-blender-part-1-why-its-broken/)
- [This video](http://vimeo.com/75992488) by Sebastian König explaining some advantages to using RMB to select
- ["Fixing Blender – Part 2" by Andrew Price](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/10/03/fixing-blender-part-2/)
- [This 3 hour discussion about Blender's interface](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/10/07/podcast-jonathan-williamson-and-andrew-price-discuss-blenders-interface/)
- ["New Blender UI Proposal" by Andrew Price](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/10/17/new-blender-ui-proposal/)
- [The manual on object selection](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/selecting.html#selecting)

Comment: Well that is annoying. Why blender why! every other program is left click. :)

Comment: @BlenderBoy This is been a topic of a lot of controversy lately..

Comment: Agreed.  but you get used to it... UNTIL you move to another app (such as image editing) and get infuriated because you're right clicking things and it's not working.

Comment: Strange. I have no problems with that whatsoever. And one big word of advice: Blender is not meant to by tried out. It's a highly complex very powerful tool that needs at least some tutorials to learn.

Comment: Lets not turn a troll question into yet another UI discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this in the **User Preferences** pane found at the top left of the main window in the **File** menu.
Next click the **Input** tab, then locate **Select With**, you will see two options which are **Left** and **Right**.

You may also want to look a little further down for **Invert Zoom Direction** if the current mouse wheel zoom seems backwards to you.

At the very bottom, you should see a button that says **Save User Settings**, click this to save the change.  Just be sure to remember this when you are following any tutorials or you will end up really confused.  It's really not a big deal once you know what's going on here.