# Where can I find the Decimate modifier?

Tags: modifiers, objects

I need to decimate a 3d-scanned image.  I am in Object Mode, but I do not see the Modifiers Panel.  The wiki says that F9 will display the Modifiers panel, but this does nothing in my Blender session.  I am running Blender 2.70 on Windows 7.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You may also try out *Mesh > Vertices > Remove Doubles* (or via `W` menu, both in *Edit Mode*).

Answer (score 3):

You must have an object selected for the modifiers panel to be visible.

Once you [have an object selected](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3446/599) (yellow outline), it will be in *Properties > Modifiers*. Then click on *Add modifier* and select *Decimate*:

[image]