# Issues with exporting fbx to unity

Tags: unity

[image: **deformed model in unity**]

My model gets messed up when I try to export it. How do I change it to be normal? Some parts of the model are missing, even after I join the model together.

eDIT- here is the download link [image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Please give us further information. What does the model look like in Blender? It says "Can't calculate tangents, because mesh 'Cube.001' doesn't contain normals." at the bottom. Did you already check the object 'Cube.001'?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Basically, what I found out was that when I import into unity it says that my model didn't have enough vertices or triangles, thus it split it into two parts.... How do I stop it from screwing up?

Comment: Unity splits up mesh if it contains more than 65,000 triangles. How many total triangles are in the mesh you're trying to import.

Comment: 76 396 triangles, I deeply apologize for my imperfections, but could you please tell me how should I go about making it, so it works? I heard that triangles shouldn't be in the model... WHat should I do?

Comment: The triangles are just the connections between the vertices. Every proper model has the triangles. I can tell you that 76,000 is too many triangles. And it may be impossible to rig the character if Unity has to split up the model into multiple meshes. For a typical character model, the number of triangles is usually no more than 20,000 triangles, as general guide. Look up the "Decimate" modifier for help on reducing triangles.  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8975/where-can-i-find-the-decimate-modifier

Comment: But does that mean, that I cannot use sub. modifier in my models, or do I just not apply it? ... or am I just stuck with a model that looks like minecraft character now?

Comment: also, it says in FBX warnings that model doesn't have tangents and binormals... what does that mean?

Comment: You have to upload the file somewhere for further help. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I added the link...

Comment: The issue is the scales are not set. IF you select the mesh and choose CTRL-A -> apply position,rotation,scale the model imports into Unity fine. Secondly, a single eyeball contains 5,000 triangles. This is too excessive. You need to reduce the number of triangles. You can select everything and separate by material. Then select individual meshes and do the decimate modifier on the separated meshes. Then rejoin everything. Keep doing it until the triangle count is reduced to a reasonable level.

Comment: I just edited the above comment.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for help... You are amazing!!!

Comment: Okay, now I tried to get it on aroun 7 500 triangles and it  looks like it's pretty much as far as I can go, do you think that it's too much for a model like this?

Comment: Well, I did as I was commanded. How exactly did it work out for you, cause after I've done what you told me, the model in unity still looks the same as on the picture, please try to specify me maybe import settings or something that might be messing it up?

Comment: Did you apply the position,rotation and scale? Generally a main character is around 10,000 to 25,000 triangles. If it's the main player character in a third person game you can get away with that many triangles. What I do is during decimation is keep decimating parts until the shading "breaks" when rendering in Unity. That is, the threshold where parts that are supposed to be smooth, no longer appear smooth because you've decimated it TOO much. Then stop there. For the eyeball, you could probably get away with just 200 triangles if you really wanted to, as opposed to 5,000 triangles.

Comment: http://imgur.com/uxkH1aI

Comment: I did apply location rotation and scale and everything seems to be the same way

Comment: It looks like some triangles are not facing the right direction. Go into edit mode, select all triangles and choose "Recalculate Normals". If it still doesn't work, upload the new file.

Comment: Now it finally woks, but it seems my textures are invisible... that's the last things I need to fix, can you work your way around that somehow? :/

Comment: Okay, it works now... thanks for everything!!!