# Where are the settings for draw distance?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

I'm completely new to Blender, I have animated some text with help from a tutorial, but that's it.

My first problem is, that i can't find the "View Properties" menu. I need to find it so I can change my "Draw Distance". (I'm not sure if it is called "Draw Distance")

[image: First problem]

Okay, so my second problem is this:
[image: What is this!?]

It is so annoying. For example, I selected a plane to drag it, and when I tried to drag it, it looked like I dragged the thing from the picture above, and not the plane. Also, when i den drag the object selected, the 3D cursor doesn't follow the object, why?

Comment: Your questions are fine. However, it would be better if they were posted separately (so it's easier to search for and find them). Thanks :)

Comment: @AskeKaiser It's not too late, you can edit your question (by clicking the edit link below your post and above these comments) and copy/paste your second question to a new post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By draw distance, I'm guessing you mean *viewport clipping distance*. Settings can be found in *3D view > Properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>) > View > Clip*:

[image]

That circle is called the 3D cursor. It's useful in many ways, once you get used to it ;) It is positioned by pressing LMB. To select and drag an object, use RMB.

See [How do I select an object in the 3D viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3446/599) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, my first question is answered. You're right, i want the 3D cursor to be centered, but i don't know what LMB and RMB is.

Comment: LMB=Left Mouse Button and RMB=Right Mouse Button.

Comment: Oh, thank you. But when i drag a object, the 3D cursor doesn't follow with that object. It did for some days ago, i don't know if i pressed something, so the 3D cursor won't lock on to objects. Is that a possibility?

Comment: @AskeKaiser I can't think of any option which would do that.. You can snap the 3D cursor to the selected object with `Shift+S` *> Cursor to selected*. Does that do what you want?

Comment: Yes, but when i then move the object, the 3D cursor doesn't stick to it.

Comment: I don't know of anything which would "glue" the 3D cursor to an object (short of using something like drivers, but there's pretty much no way you could set up a driver without knowing it)  Are you perhaps thinking of the manipulator widget? (Ctrl+Space to toggle)

Comment: Well, those lines that you drag a object around with, used to be on the object, now they're on the 3D cursor.

Comment: @AskeKaiser Oh. You pressed `.` (period), which changed the [pivot point](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point) to the 3D cursor. Press `Ctrl+,` (comma) to go back to the default. See http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point/3D_Cursor

Comment: In the top right corner of your 3D View Port there is that little Plus sign when your Properties Panel is closed which helps you to open it again ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> you'll see the Snap menu:

[image: Snap menu]

*Cursor to Selected* and *Cursor to Center* allows you to attach the 3D Cursor to the selected mesh or the center of the world space respectively.

*Selection to Cursor* allows you to move the selected mesh to the 3D Cursor.

Answer (score 2):

I would recomend to go first through the [The Interface Section](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual) of the Blender manual.

- How far an object appears is controlled by its distance to the camera <kbd>Numpad</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> (Toggle camera view).
- Left clicking places the mouse cursor (as gandalf3 already explained) when you create a new object it will appear at the position of the 3D-cursor. The 3D cursor has many other uses e.g. pivot point to rotate.