# Blender render engine is rendering just part of an object

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

When I zoom out in the view window, my object is not being shown entirely.

[image]

Can anyone help understand why this is happening and how to fix it?

My Hardware specification:
i7 2.80GHz
NVidia GTX 1050 4GB
8GB RAM
Windows 10

Comment: Possible? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Comment: Same thing, different question/answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12280/where-are-the-settings-for-draw-distance

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @rcgauer in the comments, it is a duplicated => post [Where can the viewport clipping parameters be changed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed)

I just changed the `end` clip property in the `View` group as suggested by @adhi post linked above and it worked fine.