# How to select a strip in the video sequence editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I can't seem to select a clip in the sequencer. When I try, all it does is move the scrub point. I don't want to move the scrub point, I want to select the clip. I want to move the clip around. I want to delete the clip. But I can't select the clip!

I have tried <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> clicking, <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> clicking, <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> clicking, <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd> clicking, and every combination I could think of...

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/vse/sequencer/selecting.html

Answer (score 6):

[Selecting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3446/599) is done with <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>. Also make sure you click more in the middle of the strip, as the ends of a strip can be selected separately.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Click in the middle of the strip, not the ends with the arrows.

- <kbd>A</kbd> selects/deselects all.
- <kbd>B</kbd> starts Box Select.
- Nonkeypad <kbd>Home</kbd> centers the selected strip.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>MMB</kbd> zooms.

It may be easier if the clip is of a manageable size.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. The other answers seemed to assume you were not on a Mac or that you were using a physical mouse. If you have a physical mouse (with more than one button) attached, your <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> should work to select. If not, try checking your mouse settings to make sure a right click is really a right click.

If you are using a multi-touch track pad a two finger click might work. If not go into your trackpad settings to see what combination of presses equals a right mouse button click.

I felt really dumb after figuring this out by accident. I spent a day clicking again and again grumbling against stupid Blender.