# What's that crosshair in the 3D View?

Tags: 3d-view

I'd like to know how to get rid of that crosshair that interferes with selection; it's so annoying.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3447/3710

Comment: @poor thanks. that was helpful, but I don't see a way to disable that 3d cursor alltogether, is there?

Comment: Google 3D cursor, it's one of Blender's most essential tools, when you understand it's role, you wont be asking how to disable it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select an object in the 3D viewport?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3446/how-do-i-select-an-object-in-the-3d-viewport)

Comment: Once you understand the principle, you will fall in love with it... Further reading: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24787/uses-of-the-3d-cursor

Comment: Your second question should be posted as... a second question.

Comment: @Georges This is a tough case since the questions are actually not duplicates, on the answer cross applies. The current police on SE would be to leave this question open. (There are advantages including better search indexing).

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I asked few questions before that are marked as duplicates and are still open, this helps finding more answers about the topic, I totally agree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, the 3D cursor doesn't interfere with selection.
By default LMB places the cursor, RMB selects.

The crosshair is the **3D Cursor**, it is like a cursor in a text-editor it shows where Blender will put stuff and also where the center of some operations can be set to be performed from, such as scaling, rotating, the pivot point when bending, the depth grease pencil is drawn and a point you can use to snap the selection to.

While it may seem strange at first, when you start using Blender but it becomes an indispensable tool when you get more experienced.

Here is a link to the blender manual describing the 3D cursor. https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html

Here is a quick video that will help you better understand how it works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nlk28Ex9jVQ

Answer (score 7):

The 3D cursor is one of the most used tools in blender. I can not figure out why you would want to disable it, other than it looks ugly and is interfering with your view port.

Compare:

[image]

In this picture, the view port is cluttered with lamps, empties, bounding boxes, and that ugly 3D cursor! However, you can hide all of this easily.

Simply press <kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D view to toggle open a sidebar. In it, locate the display section and check "only render"

[image]

Now only your pretty view port preview is showing!

Answer (score 3):

*This should be a comment but for visibility I will post as an answer*. As pointed out above, this is very useful when modeling. However if you find it getting in your way you can hide it without losing any other viewport markers by zooming out and then left clicking somewhere in a corner of your view, (since this is positioned in 3d space it will stay there respective of where you're located) then focus back your object <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Or we could model a missile, load it with the 3D cursor, and send it off into to 3D space!